# In Spring Boot, How do I declare that my JMS server is embedded?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

The [Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) has this very brief illustration of an embedded JMS server: "Two beans that you don’t see defined are JmsTemplate and ConnectionFactory. These are created automatically by Spring Boot. In this case, the ActiveMQ broker runs embedded." Huh? The [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms) doesn't say a thing about it. I need to create two VMs, each running from its own jar file, and I need one of them to launch an embedded JMS server, but I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody point me in the right direction. (If you provide a link, I would prefer some clear documentation over an example, but I'll be happy with a good example.)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong reference documentation. Yours is from Spring Integration.

The one of Spring Boot can be found here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-activemq

And there you will find the answer:

> When ActiveMQ is available on the classpath, Spring Boot can also
>   configure a ConnectionFactory. If the broker is present, an embedded
>   broker is automatically started and configured (provided no broker URL
>   is specified through configuration).

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was more documentation somewhere, and the other link is also called the "reference documentation." They should provide a link.

Comment: Upon further reading, it's still not clear. The phrase "if a broker is present..." is rather vague. Present where? On the classpath? This means a broker must be different from ActiveMQ, or there would be no way to avoid an embedded broker.  How do I put my broker on the classpath? (Is that where I'm supposed to put it?)  Here's where a code example might be helpful.

Comment: The documentation also fails to give me any details about the url of the embedded server, such as the port. If I specify a url, it will apparently take this to mean I don't want an embedded broker. Looking at the output of the application, it tells me it started a broker at this url: vm://localhost  Trying to connect to vm://localhost gives me "unknown protocol." Trying tcp://localhost gives me "illegal port number: -1" Trying tcp://localhost:61616 gives me "Connection Refused," as does any other port number I've tried. The documentation is no help.